# Eslint returns Assigning to rvalue for ES6 functions

Tags: javascript, express, eslint

At the moment I am using eslint with this config:

```
{
    "extends": "google",
    "installedESLint": true
}
```

When linting this function:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.send('hello world')
});
```

I get:

> ESlint: Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue

But, my code runs without problems.

Can someone explain what this error means and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create a new issue at https://github.com/eslint/eslint, or ask in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/eslint or even at https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint

Comment: might be related to this: https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a bug in babel parser, try changing the arrow function to a classic anonymous function like this for now:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  res.send('hello world')
});
```

Comment: well yes this works, but still would be nice to be able to use arrows...guess I'll just ignore that linter message for now

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your eslint config and you shouldn't get any errors when using arrow function syntax:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error (Assigning to rvalue) with the following code:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) = > {
    await next();
    });
```

Here is my config file. I've tried setting ecmaVersion to 6, 7 and 8. I previously found that I needed to set it to 8 to get it to recognize async functions. The above pattern is common when creating a web server using koajs.

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 7,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I copy and pasted code and didn't realize that the => was separated by a space into = >. Ignore my post - I'll try to delete it.